# C++ CRTP in array

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, design-patterns, crtp

Can I somehow use Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP) with array? 
What I want? I want array of classes that have some foo function. And call it for all objects in array. Like so:

```
template<class Derived>
struct Base{
  void call(){
     static_cast<Derived*>(this)->call();
  }
};    

struct A : Base<A>{
    void call(){
        cout <<"A";
    }
};

struct B : Base<B>{
    void call(){
        cout <<"B";
    }
};

...

Base array[2] = {A(), B()};  // <-- here is my array
array[0].call();
array[1].call();
```

P.S. I read, also, about AutoList pattern. But it seems it have nothing to do with my problem.

Comment: Go here to understand `struct` and `class` differences: [access specifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access)

Comment: @CPlusPlus OOA and D - Are you kidding me? Why I need this?

Comment: Because the posted answer saying `Base` is not a class is misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use another (non-templated) base and a virtual call, like this:

```
struct VirtualBase {
    virtual void call () = 0;
};

template <class Derived>
struct Base : VirtualBase {
    virtual void call () override {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->real_call ();
    }
};    

struct A : Base<A> {
    void real_call () {
        cout << "A";
    }
};

struct B : Base<B> {
    void real_call () {
        cout << "B";
    }
};
```

And use it like this:

```
VirtualBase * a [] = {new A(), new B()};

a[0]->call ();
a[1]->call ();
```

Note that to have polymorphism, you need to work with pointers or references (which is one of the problems with your code, because you are trying to put instances themselves into an array.)

Also, note the name change between `call` and `real_call`.

And don't forget to `delete` the instances; for example like this:

```
for (auto e : a) delete e;
```

or you can use `std::unique_ptr<>`, but the initialization of the array will be more verbose.

---

**Update about virtual calls, in response to comments**:

If you want to be able to dispatch to different methods determined *at runtime*, then you *have to* to use some kind of indirection. You won't be able to let the compiler bake in the call addresses at compile time (which is what happens with ordinary function calls and non-virtual method calls.)

One form of that indirection is using virtual methods; others are using function pointers, or even `switch` statements. There are other more exotic and less-used forms of call indirection too (e.g. runtime in-memory patching of addresses, etc.) but they are rarely worth the effort.

In short, if you want to have the flexibility of *runtime dispatch*, you'll have to pay the price.

---

**Update with another sample**:
In response to comments on other answers, here's [a small sample of CRTP](http://ideone.com/66KjJc) used in conjunction with polymorphism. It's just an example, and not a good one, but I see no reason why they can't be used together.

Comment: Why you still cast static_cast<Derived*>(this) ? If you make it virtual.

Comment: @tower120: That's your code. I assumed you wanted it that way. Other than that, there is no reason for it.

Comment: I tried to use CRTP to get rid of virtual call overhead. So this is impossible to do without virtual functions?

Comment: CRTP is mostly used to implement *static* polymorphism. I consider using polymorphism to solve "looping through CRTP derived classes" very much a non solution (while I'm desperatly searching for such a way, I may need  resort to function pointers...)

Answer (score 3):

You can't have an array

```
Base array[2];
```

since `Base` is not a class.

`Base<A>` and `Base<B>` are classes but the two are completely different classes, with no relationship between them.

**Update**

You could use something like what @yzt suggested but then that is hardly any more elegant than:

```
struct Base {
    virtual void call () = 0;
};


struct A : Base {
    void call () {
        cout << "A";
    }
};

struct B : Base {
    void call () {
        cout << "B";
    }
};

Base* a [] = {new A(), new B()};

a[0]->call ();
a[1]->call ();
```

The CRTP class doesn't need to be present at all.

Comment: Genial! Why would I even ask this, if it worked? I ask how to store different classes in array, and then call a function for each of them.

Comment: @tower120 You asked "Can I somehow use Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP) with array?" The answer is "No". I just explained why.

Comment: @RSahu: Wow! Way to be misleading! Of course you can use CRTP in an array.

Comment: @RSahu: Of course, there is no need for CRTP in *this simple example*, but I can think of situations were CRTP can be useful.

Comment: @yzt I agree, CRTP is useful. I have used it my work quite successfully. Have you found any usages of CRTP in a class hierarchy like you presented in your answer? If you have, I would love to learn it, if you are able to share that knowledge.

Comment: @RSahu: Here's [a small sample of CRTP](http://ideone.com/66KjJc) used in conjunction with polymorphism. It's just an example, and not a good one, but I see no reason why they can't be used together.